# Find and display only multiple name match

Tags: bash, sh

I need to use bash to strictly match multiple folders names and display these folders.
In that example folders with subfolders.

```
root_folder
  sub1
  sub2  

root_folder1
  sub1
  sub2
  sub3

root_folder2
  sub1
```

And i only need to print folder(s) which contains folders sub1 and sub3 so it should be root_folder1.

I tried such approach, it doesn't do what expected.
`find source_dir -type d \( -iname "sub1" -a -iname "sub3" \)`

Comment: Do you REALLY want the subdir name test to be case-insensitive? If so please [edit] your question to show various upper/lower case combinations and the desired output from each, including a directory that contains `sub1` and `SUB1` but not any variant of `sub3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` can't do this by itself. Use `find` to find all directories, then pipe this to a loop that checks if it contains `sub1` and `sub3`:

```
find source_dir -type d | while read -r dir; do
    if [[ -d "$dir/sub1" && -d "$dir/sub3" ]]
    then printf "%s\n" "$dir"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Great, works as expected as other answers too, but chosen yours as it more specific for my task as i need execute command between if statement against found folders.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
tree .
.
├── folder0
│   ├── sub1
│   │   ├── file1
│   │   ├── file2
│   │   └── file3
│   └── sub2
├── folder1
│   ├── sub1
│   ├── sub2
│   └── sub3
└── folder2
    └── sub1
10 directories, 3 files
```

You may as well use Bash completely to recursively loop the directory structure.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar      # not required in zsh

for dir in ./*/**/; do # with the trailing '/' only directories
    [[ -d "$dir/sub1" && -d "$dir/sub3" ]] && echo "$dir"
done
```

Note that `shopt -s globstar` enables recursive globbing in Bash and is required to make this work (except on zsh).

---

If you have a whole list of targets to test:

```
#!/bin/bash

tgts=( "sub1" "sub2" "sub3" )
find . -type d  | while read -r dir; do 
    for sd in "${tgts[@]}"; do 
        [[ -d "$dir/$sd" ]] || continue 2
    done
    echo "$dir/"
done
```

---

If you want POSIX style loop, you could use `find` to find one subdirectory then test for the other:

```
#!/bin/sh

find . -type d -name sub1 | while read -r dir; do 
    parent="${dir%/*}/"          # parent="$(dirname "$dir")/" if you prefer
    [ -d "${parent}sub3" ] && echo "$parent"
done
```

---

Or if you are on a prehistoric shell that does not support recursive globs you could use Ruby:

```
ruby -e 'Dir.glob(".*/**/").each{|dir| 
    puts dir if Dir.exist?("#{dir}/sub3") && Dir.exist?("#{dir}/sub3")}'
```

Any of those prints `./folder1/`

Comment: I love this approach, and it's usually what I do in my day to day work, but I think it will miss "hidden" (named with a leading dot) sub paths... which I consider a feature, not a bug, but is worthy of note.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a simple search for one as my base set criteria, then just check for the other. This approach can make the `find` a bit quicker and less noisy, as it only returns directories that already match at least one, so you just have to check for the other one. It also doesn't spawn a lot of subshells.

As Ed pointed out, though, this isn't doing case-INsensitive comparisons.

```
find "$wherever" -type d -name "sub1" |
 while read -r dir; do [[ -d "${dir/%1/3}" ]] && echo "${dir%/sub1}"; done
```

Using:

```
$: find ?
1
1/.noseeme
1/.noseeme/sub1
1/.noseeme/sub3
1/sub1
1/sub2
2
2/sub1
2/sub1/sub1
2/sub1/sub3
2/sub2
2/sub3
3
3/sub1
3/sub1/sub3
```

This gives me:

```
$: find . -type d -name "sub1" | 
>   while read -r dir
>   do [[ -d "${dir/%1/3}" ]] && echo "${dir%/sub1}"
>   done
./1/.noseeme
./2
./2/sub1
```

If you ***know*** that you don't have anything like a dot-prefixed hidden path that might have a hit you want to include (etc), you can skip the `find`.

In your example above, where everything is at known depth, it's very simple -

```
$: for dir in */sub1/; do [[ -d "${dir/%1\//3}" ]] && echo "${dir%/sub1?}"; done;
2
```

Obviously, this missed `./1/.noseeme` and `./2/sub1` which each had both. That might be a feature, if you ONLY wanted the specified depth, and/or to ignore hidden paths.

Otherwise, as dawg said, try `extglob`.

```
$: shopt -s extglob
$: for dir in ./**/sub1/; do [[ -d "${dir/%1\//3}" ]] && echo "${dir%/sub1?}"; done
./2
./2/sub1
```

This finds arbitrary depth, but still skips hidden paths.

You could also add more glob patterns to pick up the hidden paths as well, but at that point, I wouldn't without a compelling reason.

Finally, if you need this to parse a *large* folder structure with a lot of hits, it might be slow, but `awk` (this example is [GNU specific](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-File-Functions.html)) or perl would probably speed it up with something like these -

```
$: awk '@load "filefuncs"; { stat(gensub(/sub1$/, "sub3", 1), b);
    if (b["type"] == "directory") print gensub(/[/]*sub1$/,"",1);
 }' < <(find . -type d -name "sub1")
./1/.noseeme
./2
./2/sub1

$: perl -lne 's/sub1$/sub3/; s,/sub3$,, and print if -d' < <(find . -type d -name "sub1")
./1/.noseeme
./2
./2/sub1
```

But for small scopes, the difference is irrelevant milliseconds.

---

If you really did want to ignore case sensitivity, that introduces a significant complication, particularly for this way of doing things. In that case, better to go with a slight variation of Ed's logic -

```
awk '{sub("/[^/]+$","")} seen[tolower($0)]++' < <( find . -type d -iname "sub[13]" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't really want the subdir name tests to be case-insensitive then, using any awk (untested):

```
find dir -type d \( -name "sub1" -o -name "sub3" \) |
awk '{sub("/[^/]+$","")} cnt[$0]++'
```

Comment: So... the `find` lists all paths of sub1 or sub3, then the `awk` strips the last node and prints *if* the rest of the path has been seen before. A little hard to parse as a human, but elegant. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
find source_dir -type d -exec bash -c 'cd $1; test -d sub1 -a -d sub3' _ {} \; -print
```